# UML - Sequence diagram life lines

Tags: uml

On a sequence diagram, what does the vertical thin rectangles on the object life line signify ? I could not find a proper answer after searching a lot .  Would some one please help me understand this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nice question I must say a rare one. Nobody bother on that but uses.

Comment: @SanjayaLiyanage this wasn't a rare one, it already has a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for displaying one interaction of the object with other object or itself. Interaction needs to be started within that rectangle in the top side and end near bottom side. There is no need to start or end interaction in the top most or bottom most edges in the rectangle. Some also call these as Execution Specifications as well. Have a look at some examples [here](http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/)

Comment: Do it mean that each of it represent a method call to other object ?    Also to represent more than one interaction, will there be more than one rectangle bars on the object life line ?

Comment: Yes a method call of another object is a interaction. Of course there can be several rectangles in the life line one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence diagram life lines represent  different processes or objects that live simultaneously.Lifelines represent only one interacting entity.It is basically a vertical dashed line that represents existence of an object over a period of time.This line disappears when the object is destroyed.As for example see the diagram below:

[image]

The **data** here is an object of type **Stock**.We can show all the interactions among objects like message exchanges on these lifelines.Just take a look at the diagram below describing interaction between a computer and a server :

[image]

Note that the thin vertical rectangles represent [execution specification](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#execution).

**Execution specification** is a part of object's interaction which represents period of object's lifetime when it is either doing some activity or simply waiting for the reply from other object.

Notation for execution specification is as follows:

[image]